# Nancy.Viewengines.Razor Error with Dependency to Microsoft.AspNet.Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nancy, razorengine

When I installed this library by nuget: install-package nancy.ViewEngines.Razor
I can't commpile project:

> Error 1   This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
>   this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For
>   more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567.    c:\users\piotr.rabiniak\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects....

Comment: Just got this as well - I'll post any updates that I can discover.

Comment: An issue has been created at Github: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1593

Comment: As a temporary measure, I removed the Nuget references, then added the assemblies from the share.  It builds, and allows me to do what I need until a fix is posted.

Comment: Problem manifested after updating from a slightly earlier version of the already present Nancy.Viewengines.Razor package.
Removing the Nancy.Viewengines.Razor package then forcing install of version 0.23.0 has worked around the problem.

`Install-Package Nancy.Viewengines.Razor -Version 0.23.0`

Comment: It seems that community from #nancyfx project fix that bug in https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1593